# How do I keep track of different scripts with the same version number in change history table from snowflake schema change?

Tags: github, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, schema, github-actions, snowflake-schema

I am following the demo template for Snowflake schema change. I already have one script recorded in my change_history table:

[Current script recorded in change history table, which has a version of 1.1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkRPM.png)

In Github, I set up a separate environment file to have a path to a different, unrelated script which also has a version of 1.1.1, I want this script to be recorded in the change_history table as well:

[Different script which also has a version of 1.1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ4uk.png)

When I run my action script, it finishes with success but the different script is not recorded in the change_history table. It keeps only the first script. From what I can tell it will not update unless I give my new script a different number. But in essence this is a completely separate script from the first one. How can I keep records of both scripts as V1.1.1 in the change_history table via schemachange?

[Finished with success, but change_history table does not add the new script.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dT543.png)

Comment: I'm curious why you wouldn't include them as different version numbers. The way versioning works is from an imperative approach to DevOps, where all that matters are the incremental changes running one after the other. It looks like you want to put this in a different path to structure your code a certain way, which is closer to the declarative way of doing things. You can still do that but you do have to follow the ordering of different versions to specific which file run after the next. There would be no way for schemachange to know which SQL to run in order without the version numbers

Comment: Maybe I had a fundamental misunderstanding of versioning here. Yes, I think I wanted to go the declarative change route. I am used to SCCS version control, in which each individual script had its own version, scriptA could have 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, while scriptB could have 1.1, 1.2. They would be in their own locations, there would be no overlap, and they both have their own individual functions, say one is a table for warehouses and the other is a table for sales. I guess I find it confusing how scripts for different purposes would share the same incremental version number. Thank you.

Comment: Versioning is intended to indicate a version for an entire database or the snowflake account, not just one area of the database. The folders you create in schemachange are arbitrary. You always need to tell an imperative tool which change to run first. Tools like Terraform or dbt take a more declarative approach to organizing and running your changes and focus on you maintaining a definition of the object you want to control.